# How should i use setTimeout in this js code in lightning component so that popup opens after 2 min?

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, developer, lightning-development

```
 const isCookie = getCookie('pre-trial-survey');
 if(!isCookie && IS_GUEST) {
  setCookie('pre-trial-survey', false, 30); 
  this.showPopup=true;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  }, 120000);//2 minutes, since 1 sec=1000
      }
  else{
    this.showPopup = false;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const isCookie = getCookie('pre-trial-survey');
 if(!isCookie && IS_GUEST) {
  setCookie('pre-trial-survey', false, 30); 
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.showPopup=true;
 }, 120000);//2 minutes=120000, since 1 sec=1000 

      }
  else{
    this.showPopup = false;
  }
```

}

Comment: This code worked for me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Checkout this link for more information